# stanford tagger: error deleting last token

Tags: java

I am using tagger for tagging tokens and stanford-postagger-3.4.1 jar 
i am using this code for tagging

```
tagger = new MaxentTagger("conf" + File.separatorChar + "wsj-0-18-bidirectional-distsim.tagger");
```

It is deleting last token while tagging 
For ex. "Chefs Matthew has a special lunch for the value conscious too, priced at Rs. 178."

```
String strInputSen = tagger.tagString(inputsentence);
```

Final tagged output is:

```
"Chefs_NNP Matthew_NNP has_VBZ a_DT special_JJ lunch_NN for_IN the_DT value_NN conscious_JJ too_RB ,_, priced_VBN at_IN Rs_NN ._. "
Last token 178 is deleted.
```

what is the reason for this - is it a problem in tagger or jar?

Comment: Is it delete last word all the times? Even if it is a word?

Comment: NOt in this example.but if i am using tag tokinizedstring() will it work fine??

Comment: Any progress on this problem? I'm running into the same thing.